# Form Filter using DateSerial does not work correctly

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to filter a form between dates - first and last of the next month. My coding for the last seems to work.I have also made a text box which does return the date I want but the same code in the filter is returning dates from 01 Jan 2013.

```
Public Function DtFrom() As Date

    DtFrom = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 1)

End Function

Me.Filter = "[DateDue] Between #" & DtFrom & "# And #" & (DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 2, 1) - 1) & "#"
```

Answer (score 0):

"[DateDue] Between #" & DtFrom() & "# And #" &

make sure you are calling the function DtFrom()  'yes you need the parenthesis